# Play framework Image.resize on png losing transparency

Tags: model-view-controller, upload, playframework, image, image-resizing

I am using play framework 1.2.4. I am having a problem with Image.resize() method that is removing transparency in png images?

My code looks like this:

```
public static void uploadPhoto(int user_id, File picture) throws IOException{

        Images.resize(picture, picture, 200, 200, true);

        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(picture);
        user.getPerson().setPicture(IOUtils.toByteArray(f));
        user.getPerson().save();
        ...
    }
```

I would like to know how to do resize without losing PNG transparency?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `play.libs.Images` https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/libs/Images.java, when the new sized image is set up (line 102), the image is defaulted to a White background. This looks like why your transparency is being lost.

I guess this is a bug.